# On iOS, the keyboard does not offer a 6-character SMS code

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I'm developing a mobile application in React Native. The application has the `<TextInput/>` for entering SMS codes:

```js
const [pinCode, setPinCode] = useState('');
const pinCodeRef = useRef();

// crutch so that the user's keyboard opens automatically
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    pinCodeRef.current.focus();
  }, 400);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);

}, []);

...

<TextInput 
  placeholder="Enter pin-cpde" 
  placeholderTextColor={commonStyles.colors.label}
  value={pinCode}
  onChangeText={val => setPinCode(val)}
  maxLength={6}
  ref={pinCodeRef}
  keyboardType="number-pad"
  autoComplete="sms-otp"
  textContentType="oneTimeCode"
/>
```

I use properties `keyboardType="number-pad" autoComplete="sms-otp" textContentType="oneTimeCode"` to have the keyboard prompt the user for an SMS code.

**The problem is that 6-digit codes on IOS are not prompted, while 4-digit codes work correctly. On Android everything works correctly.**

About app:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 141.94 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.18.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Libraries (for example `react-native-otp-auto-fill`) did not cope with the code hint (on IOS and ob Android). Only the properties mentioned above helped me.

P.S. The SMS text is the same (only the code length differs)

Comment: that's why I use textContentType="oneTimeCode" additonal

Comment: @James I use react native v0.67